# How open Chrome without url field from shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, browser, command-line

Are there anyway to open Chrome without url field from shortcut? What flags ara neccesary to open it? Commnad line flags (Windows)

I know that I can open Chrome from command line in new tab: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "http://marcodetrabajo.com"

I need it without url field, only web content.

Info: [link](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/)

Maybe, with another browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. The solotion in Chrome browser is:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

No flags are needed. Just open CMD and type:

`start chrome example.com`

If you want to open multiple pages in multiple tabs:

`start chrome \example.com \google.com`